# Is $\{\varnothing\}$ a subset of $\varnothing$, the empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Formed a table for a competitive exam:

$\begin{array}{cc}
\text{True} & \text{False} \\
\hline
\varnothing\subseteq\varnothing & \varnothing \in \varnothing\\
\varnothing\subseteq\{\varnothing\} & \,\\
\varnothing\in\{\varnothing\} & \{\varnothing\}\in\varnothing\\
\{\varnothing\}\subseteq\{\varnothing\} & \{\varnothing\}\in\{\varnothing\}
\end{array}$

I wish to know if $\{\varnothing\} \subseteq \varnothing$?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: sure :) would remember in future..new to this

Comment: How many elements does each of the sets have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

{$\emptyset$} is not a sub-set of $\emptyset$

What's more: if A is a set it's never the case that {A} is a sub-set of A. 
The latter is true because if you assume {A} is a sub-set of A, this implies that **A belongs to A**. But that would mean that you need A to define A (because a set is defined by giving its elements). OK, I am talking only about well-founded set theories here. But these are usually the theories studied in schools/universities, so you're safe to remember that fact above.

Comment: Regarding your second statement, this is what I thought a long time too but apparently there are some crazy set theory where it's not true.

Comment: I understand that the latter justifies the former, but I think you should justify the latter statement or at least give the OP a hint as to show to justify it.

Comment: @Surb Such as?.

Comment: @BCLC I don't remember honestly this came out in another MSE question. Maybe a set theoretist will pass by and give such an example.

Comment: @Surb: In particular, [non-well-founded set theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory) admit objects $x$ such that $x=\{x\}$, in which case $\{x\}\subseteq x$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks for the example. I'll keep it in mind this time :)

Answer (score 8):

Hint: The question is asking if all the elements in $\{\emptyset\}$ are in $\emptyset$. Since $\{\emptyset\}$ has 1 element, namely $\emptyset$, we want to check if that element is in $\emptyset$ (as in, the set on the RHS of the inclusion statement).

What are the elements of $\emptyset$?

Comment: I suspect you may profit from the remark that the braces $\{\}$ are rendered as `\{\}`.

Comment: What a hassle. Extra \'s just for that? Anyway thanks @Lord_Farin. I now know what to do about nested brackets in the future.

Comment: It's a workaround because the braces are used in TeX for grouping purposes: Compare $x^{12}$ (`x^{12}`) and $x^12$ (`x^12`). For further information about writing maths on this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Comment: @Lord_Farin Thanks, but I know about TeX. I just find it a hassle to use curly brackets in something like this. However, again, I think it may be helpful for nested brackets so again thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :).

Comment: @Lord_Farin I profited from this. Some things just NEED curly brackets :))

Answer (score 2):

Definition: $(A\subseteq B\iff (x\in A\,\Rightarrow\, x\in B))$.

Here: $(x\in \{\varnothing\}\,\Leftrightarrow\, x=\varnothing\,\not\Rightarrow\, x\in\varnothing)$,

since it is impossible to be an element of $\varnothing$, so $\{\varnothing\}\not\subseteq\varnothing$.

More generally, $\{A\}\not\subseteq A$ (equivalently $A\not\in A$) for any set $A$, which is implied by the [Axiom of regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) (a part of the usual ZFC, regarded as the most common and standard axiomatic set theory).